# Problems upgrading Postgresql in Gitlab from PG12 to PG13

Tags: postgresql, gitlab, openshift

I am currently trying to update gitlab with Helm on an Openshift 4.11 from 15.11.13 to 16.1.5 and need to upgrade my Postresql database too. Unfortunately its running into a problem.

gitlab-studio-backup$ curl -s “https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab/-/raw/v7.1.5/scripts/database-upgrade” | bash -s -x – -r gitlab-dev-release -n gitlab-dev pre

```
set -e
fake_timestamp=database_upgrade_6
script_name=database-upgrade
getopts :r:n:b: opt
case “${opt}” in
release=gitlab-dev-release
getopts :r:n:b: opt
case “${opt}” in
namespace=‘-n gitlab-dev’
getopts :r:n:b: opt
shift 4
case ${1} in
pre
in_toolbox backup-utility -t database_upgrade_6 --skip registry,uploads,artifacts,lfs,packages,external_diffs,terraform_state,ci_secure_files,repositories,pages
++ grep -v backup
+++ selector toolbox
+++ base=app=toolbox
++ head -n 1
+++ ‘[’ -n gitlab-dev-release ‘]’
+++ base+=,release=gitlab-dev-release
+++ echo app=toolbox,release=gitlab-dev-release
++ kubectl -n gitlab-dev get pods -l app=toolbox,release=gitlab-dev-release --field-selector status.phase=Running -o custom-columns=N:.metadata.name --no-headers
task_pod=gitlab-dev-release-toolbox-65c4d44458-7b2vh
kubectl -n gitlab-dev exec -it gitlab-dev-release-toolbox-65c4d44458-7b2vh -c toolbox – env GITLAB_ASSUME_YES=1 backup-utility -t database_upgrade_6 --skip registry,uploads,artifacts,lfs,packages,external_diffs,terraform_state,ci_secure_files,repositories,pages
Unable to use a TTY - input is not a terminal or the right kind of file
2023-11-02 18:01:04 +0100 – Dumping database …
Dumping PostgreSQL database gitlabhq_production … pg_dump: warning: could not find where to insert IF EXISTS in statement "-- not dropping schema, since initdb creates it
"
[DONE]
2023-11-02 18:01:08 +0100 – Dumping database … done
2023-11-02 17:01:08 +0000 – Deleting backup and restore lock file
Packing up backup tar
ERROR: Error parsing xml: mismatched tag: line 66, column 4
ERROR: b’\r\n \r\n \r\n\r\n \r\n body {\r\n font-family: “Helvetica Neue”, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;\r\n line-height: 1.66666667;\r\n font-size: 16px;\r\n color: #333;\r\n background-color: #fff;\r\n margin: 2em 1em;\r\n }\r\n h1 {\r\n font-size: 28px;\r\n font-weight: 400;\r\n }\r\n p {\r\n margin: 0 0 10px;\r\n }\r\n .alert.alert-info {\r\n background-color: #F0F0F0;\r\n margin-top: 30px;\r\n padding: 30px;\r\n }\r\n .alert p {\r\n padding-left: 35px;\r\n }\r\n ul {\r\n padding-left: 51px;\r\n position: relative;\r\n }\r\n li {\r\n font-size: 14px;\r\n margin-bottom: 1em;\r\n }\r\n p.info {\r\n position: relative;\r\n font-size: 20px;\r\n }\r\n p.info:before, p.info:after {\r\n content: “”;\r\n left: 0;\r\n position: absolute;\r\n top: 0;\r\n }\r\n p.info:before {\r\n background: #0066CC;\r\n border-radius: 16px;\r\n color: #fff;\r\n content: “i”;\r\n font: bold 16px/24px serif;\r\n height: 24px;\r\n left: 0px;\r\n text-align: center;\r\n top: 4px;\r\n width: 24px;\r\n }\r\n\r\n @media (min-width: 768px) {\r\n body {\r\n margin: 6em;\r\n }\r\n }\r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n
\r\n
Application is not available
\r\n

The application is currently not serving requests at this endpoint. It may not have been started or is still starting.
\r\n\r\n
\r\n

\r\n Possible reasons you are seeing this page:\r\n
\r\n
    \r\n
    \r\n The host doesn't exist.\r\n Make sure the hostname was typed correctly and that a route matching this hostname exists.\r\n
    \r\n
    \r\n The host exists, but doesn't have a matching path.\r\n Check if the URL path was typed correctly and that the route was created using the desired path.\r\n
    \r\n
    \r\n Route and path matches, but all pods are down.\r\n Make sure that the resources exposed by this route (pods, services, deployment configs, etc) have at least one pod running.\r\n
    \r\n \r\n
\r\n
\r\n \r\n\r\n’
WARNING: Upload failed: /database_upgrade_6_gitlab_backup.tar (503 (Service Unavailable))
WARNING: Retrying on lower speed (throttle=0.01)
WARNING: Waiting 3 sec…
```

I tried to find any solutions on this problem but could not find anything that could help me.

Comment: I think you will need to find the source of this error: `Error parsing xml: mismatched tag: line 66, column 4`.

Comment: I also tried to check that. But i could not find out were the line is supposed to be. Its not the curled script i executed. there it refers just to a if statement. I could not found out were it changes the script to the one thats being executed.

Comment: It's not impossible that you have xml in the database backup, but it's unlikely. The log doesn't suggest you are restoring a dtabase at that time either

Answer (score 0):

Target port configuration were false. The GUI didnt properly show it in the normal view. In the Edit mode you could see the missing port configs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).